# Appcelerator SQLite Replace or Update Command

Tags: javascript, android, sql, sqlite, appcelerator

Table looks likes this.
table name: uzerz
(username, password, image, description)

example:
(jello, thepassword, defaultimage, defualtdescript)

need an update or replace command
to update the image with a new string where username = jello.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

var DBinsertit = Titanium.Database.open('db9');

DBinsertit.execute('UPDATE uzerz SET image = ? WHERE username = ?', changedImage, USERNAMElogin);

Found it. Have a good day!